# Best way to pass parameter in named router

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have two named router widgets, how should I pass parameter from one to another with bloc pattern?

```
// main.dart

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<OneBloc>(create: (BuildContext context) => OneBloc()),
        BlocProvider<TwoBloc>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => TwoBloc())
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'testApp',
        initialRoute: '/one',
        routes: {
          '/one': (context) => One(),
          '/two': (context) => Two()
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

// one_bloc.dart

class OneBloc extends Bloc<OneEvent, OneState> {
  OneBloc() : super(OneInitial());

  @override
  Stream<OneState> mapEventToState(
    OneEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is PassParameter) {
      yield NavigateToTwo('parameter from One');
    }
  }
}

// one_state.dart

@immutable
abstract class OneState extends Equatable {
  const OneState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class NavigateToTwo extends OneState {
  final String parameter;

  NavigateToTwo(this.parameter);
}

// One.dart -- part of UI code

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<OneBloc, OneState>(listener: (context, state) {
      if (state is NavigateToTwo) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/two'); // how to pass the state.parameter to TwoBloc
      }
    },
    // other code.
```

UPDATE

After checking the todo example in [official web site](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial), it should use StreamSubscription in TwoBloc to listen the OneBloc NavigateToTwo state to get the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have create a class variable to receive the parameter you want to pass between classes.

```
Class One {
  final a;
  One({this.a});
...
}
```

You can pass parameter through navigator as arguments like this

```
Map<String, dynamic> myArguments = {"argumentKey": value};
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/two', arguments: myArgument);
```

Then you can access this argument in onGenerateRoute() of MaterialApp like this

```
MaterialApp(
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  final args = settings.arguments;
  if (settings.name == '/one') {
    final argumentForPageOne = args["argumentForPageOne"];
  }
  if (settings.name == '/two') {
    final argumentForPageTwo = args["argumentForPageTwo"];
  }
  Map<String, Widget> widgets = {
    '/one': One(a: argumentForPageOne),
    '/two': Two(b: argumentForPageTwo)
 }
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return widgets[settings.name];
        },
      );
    }
  },
);
```

For larger projects with a number of screens, you have to create custom router class for navigation.

Example:

```
class RouterService {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigationKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  Route<dynamic> generateRoutes(RouteSettings settings) {
  final List<String> validRoutes = [
    '/home',
    '/introduction',
  ];
  PageRouteBuilder<dynamic> customRoutes(
    String route, Map<String, dynamic> args) {
    String message;
    bool showTutorial;
    if (args != null) {
      if (args.containsKey('message')) {
       message = args['message'];
      }
      if (args.containsKey('showTutorial')) {
        showTutorial = args['showTutorial'];
      } 
    }
    Map<String, Widget> screens = {
      '/home': HomeScreen(
        message: message,
        showTutorial: showTutorial,
      ),
      '/introduction': IntroductionScreen(),
      ...
    };

    return PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => screens[route],
        transitionsBuilder: (_, anim, __, child) => FadeTransition(
            opacity: anim,
            child: child,
          ),
        transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 250));
    }
  }
  if (validRoutes.contains(settings.name)) {
    return customRoutes(settings.name, settings.arguments);
  } else {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
      return NotFoundScreen();
    });
  }
}
```

Then use this custom router in MaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
  ...,
  onGenerateRoute: RouterService().generateRoutes,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

first on your MaterialApp
add this

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings){
    ///write your code here
}
```

MaterialApp will run the onGenerateRoute when your widget tree is changed. Then it has (settings) properties which you can use to get the arguments with

```
settings.arguments
```

in case you wondering where the hell arguments are from. Let me take you back to the Navigator.

```
Usually, you can use it to pass the data on the arguments key, like this 
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "your routeName", arguments:"your object here");
```

Lets back to the onGenerateRoute
this is the full example of onGenerateRoute usage

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings){
MaterialPageRoute routes;
switch (settings.name) {
    case OrderDetail.routeName:
      dynamic args = settings.arguments;
      routes = MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return OrderDetail(args);
        },
      );
      break;
    case ShowLocation.routeName:
      dynamic args = settings.arguments;
      routes = MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return ShowLocation(args);
        },
      );
      break;
    case AddressDetail.routeName:
      dynamic args = settings.arguments;
      routes = MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return AddressDetail(args);
        },
      );
      break;
  }
  return routes;
}
```

conclusion :

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings){
    settings.name;/// This will return a routeName which you called on the navigator pushNamed
    settings.arguments;/// This will return an object which you invoked on the navigator pushNamed it can be anything (dynamic) but also it can be specific, depends on what you set on the onGenerate Route !!
    ///Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeName, arguments:"your args");
}
```

Goodluck